# visual basic clicking a button from a user control that opens another user control

Tags: vb.net

Please try to understand this, I'm not really good at speaking English.

What I want to happen in my application is..

I click a button from a user-control then
another user-control shows up.

Another thing is..

I want to edit details from something in a datagridview in a user control1
by clicking a cell in the datagridview then it would open up another user control2 where the details from the datagridview are in the textboxes in the user control 2

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We like to help you, but at first you have to try on your own. Please do some research, try to do the stuff you want and once you have any problems please come back to us and ask a specific question. :)

Comment: Sorry. I tried if usercontrol1.button1 is clicked then usercontrol2.show

Comment: and I think what im trying to do is making the user-control like a panel that has a bunch of things on it